# Rails 3 multiple layout question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

Can i have more than one layout per action -

What i want is - "show.html.erb" template to be contained in "layouts/users.html.erb" and this to be contained in "layouts/application.html.erb"

Basically I want application to be the global layout container, but i also want to use intermediate layouts containers between the action template & the final application layout.

If yes, can you point me to some help topics, links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Nested-Layout plugin:

[http://nested-layouts.rubyforge.org](http://nested-layouts.rubyforge.org/)

You can follow the instructions in "Sorta Nested Layouts":

http://mattmccray.com/archive/2007/02/19/Sorta_Nested_Layouts/

But what I would recommend is using named yield and content_for statements:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts

This approach lets you specify content for specific parts of your page and generally results in much cleaner and more readable code.

Answer (score 3):

See the ["Nested Layouts" section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts) of the "Layouts and Rendering" guide.